# Swift - want to make changes when a button clicked which is inside a collection view cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have created a collection view cell which include a UIView and inside the UIView, there is a button.
What I'm trying to do is when the button clicked it will change the UIView border color.
And I load data from server and display it to the collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CypherCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CypherCollectionViewCell

    cell.tickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tickButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@objc func tickButtonClicked( sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        // To change the UIView border color
    } else {
       sender.isSelected = true
       // To change the UIView border color
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: code looks fine, check if user interaction enabled.

Comment: Code doesn't look fine. What do you use to change the view border color? `cell.view.borderColor`? If so where did you get the cell from in `ticketButtonClicked` ?

Comment: This is bad implementation. You should have the button action inside the cell.

Comment: sorry my bad, missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the button points into viewpoints and get the desired cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CypherCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CypherCollectionViewCell

    cell.tickButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tickButtonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@objc func tickButtonClicked( sender: UIButton) {

    var convertedPoint : CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self. collectionView)
    var indexPath = self. collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(convertedPoint)
    let cell = self. collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CypherCollectionViewCell

    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        // To change the UIView border color
        cell.view.borderColor = UIColor.blue()
    } else {
       sender.isSelected = true
       // To change the UIView border color
        cell.view.borderColor = UIColor.red()
    }
}
```